# Presenting UIImagePickerController from modal UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am trying to have it so a user can choose a photo from their album into an imageview. It seems to work fine if I'm using a push segue to that viewcontroller that has the button to perform the action, but when I change it to modal segue, nothing happens when I click the button to run the function. What is the cause of this exactly?

Method:

```
- (IBAction)choosePhotoFromAlbum:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imgPicker.delegate = self;
    imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self.navigationController presentViewController:imgPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: You're trying to present it from the navigation controller, but your view controller is modal. Change `[self.navigationController presentViewController:imgPicker animated:YES completion:nil];` to `[self presentViewController:imgPicker animated:YES completion:nil]`

Comment: Wow I feel like an idiot, thanks so much man!

Comment: No problem! I've added it as an answer so if you could accept it it'd be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to present it from the navigation controller, but your view controller is modal. Change

`[self.navigationController presentViewController:imgPicker animated:YES completion:nil];`

to

`[self presentViewController:imgPicker animated:YES completion:nil];`.

Answer (score 1):

you're trying to present it from the navigation controller, but your view controller is modal.  so just write

```
 [self presentViewController:YourImagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];.
```